Page numbering in table of contents goes wrong after list of tables and list of figures
I have written my PhD thesis as a Quarto book, outputting to pdf. Just about to submit final copy (viva and corrections complete), just noticed the page numbering in the Table of Contents (TOC) goes wrong at the List of Tables (LOT) and List of Figures (LOF). The TOC seems to only allow for 1 page each for the TOC, LOT and LOF, but together they are 11 pages, so all subsequent numbering in the TOC is out by 8 pages. The TOC links to book sections still work correctly.
I think the issue will be with the template partials that I found + copied (e.g. from https://cameronpatrick.com/post/2023/07/quarto-thesis-formatting/#sec-additional-front-matter) to move the TOC from the start of the book to after the Acknowledgements section (to comply with university thesis regulations). See below for YAML, template partials and code at end of section before TOC/LOT/LOF. Thank you for any help, I am new to coding and LaTeX.
YAML:
project:
  type: book
  output-dir: _book

book:
  title: "Tracheostomy tubes" 
  author:
   - name: "XXXXXX"
  date: "August 2024"
  date-format: "MMMM YYYY"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - declaration_page.qmd
    - abstract.qmd
    - acknowledgements.qmd
    - abbreviations.qmd
    - intro.qmd
  
  appendices:
    - appendix-A.qmd
    - appendix-B.qmd
    
number: true
mainfont: Arial
fontsize: "12"
linestretch: 1.5
bibliography: references.bib
csl: springer-vancouver.csl

format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
    classoption: nottoc
    papersize: a4
    template-partials:
      - before-body.tex
      - toc.tex
    tbl-cap-location: top
    lof: true
    lot: true
    page-breaks: true
    geometry:
      - inner=3cm
      - outer=3cm
      - top=2cm
      - bottom=2cm
      - headsep=8pt
      - headheight=4pt
      - footskip=33pt
      - ignorehead
      - ignorefoot
      - heightrounded
    linestretch: 1.5
    include-in-header: 
      text: |
        \usepackage{typearea}
        \usepackage{setspace}
        \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
        \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
        \usepackage{fancyhdr}
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
        \usepackage{tocbibind}

editor: visual

before-body.tex:
$if(has-frontmatter)$
\frontmatter
$endif$
$if(title)$
\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\centering
\hbox{}\vskip 0cm plus 1fill
{\Huge\bfseries $title$ \par}
$if(subtitle)$
\vspace{3ex}
{\Large\bfseries $subtitle$ \par}
$endif$
\vspace{12ex}
$for(by-author)$
{\Large\bfseries $by-author.name.literal$ \par}
\vspace{3ex}
{\bfseries\large Student number: 20155611 \par}
\vspace{3ex}
{\large $by-author.orcid$ \par}
\vskip 0cm plus 1fill
{\bfseries\Large UCL \par}
\vspace{3ex}
{\bfseries\large $date$ \par}
\vspace{6ex}
$for(by-author.affiliations)$%
{\bfseries\large $it.name$ \par}
$endfor$$endfor$%
\vspace{6ex}
{\large Submitted in partial fulfilment of the requirements
of the degree of Doctor of Philosophy \par}
\vspace{12ex}
}
$endif$
\let\mainmatterreal\mainmatter
\let\mainmatter\relax

toc.tex:
$if(toc)$
$if(toc-title)$
\renewcommand*\contentsname{$toc-title$}
$endif$
$if(colorlinks)$
\hypersetup{linkcolor=$if(toccolor)$$toccolor$$else$$endif$}
$endif$
\setcounter{tocdepth}{$toc-depth$}
$endif$
\renewcommand*\listfigurename{List of figures}
\renewcommand*\listtablename{List of tables}

Code at end of Acknowledgements section to bring in TOC/LOT/LOF:
\newpage
\setstretch{1}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\newpage
\setstretch{1.5}

I have tried adding back bits that were cut from original toc.tex (except for the call for TOC/LOT/LOF), no difference.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Guess (because I can only handle minimal working examples in LaTeX not some mixture of YAML and LaTeX code): You should not use tocbibind with KOMA-Script class scrreprt. Use the options and features of KOMA-Script classes and package tocbasic, which is already loaded and used by the class.

Thank you for this! I will look at tocbasic. Out of interest, the same ToC pagination problem occurred without tocbibind, but I added it to get the LoT and LoF displayed in the ToC. Using Quarto certainly adds complications!
